# How AFNetworking to join request timeout and network impassability verification?

Tags: timeout, afnetworking

I use `AFNetworking + SVProgressHUD post` to request data. `SVProgressHUD` will always display if the Network has a problem or very slow and internet links have been cut.

How `AFNetworking` to judge the network problem? Or request timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the implementation is for SVProgressHUD but I'm using a similar one called MBProgressHUD in my current application. Hopefully this advice still applies.

If I understand your question correctly, you're wondering how to dismiss your progressHUD if the AFNetworking call fails? If that's your question, then all you need to do is dismiss your HUD in your failure block as shown below.

```
MBProgressHUD *HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
[navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];

HUD.dimBackground = YES;
[HUD show:YES];

//Set up the request
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"example.com"]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//Set up the operation
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation  alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        // Hide activity indicator after success
        [HUD show:NO];
        [HUD hide:YES];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    // Hide activity indicator after failure
    [HUD show:NO];
    [HUD hide:YES];
}];

// Fire off the operation
[operation start];
```